# Formatting html_text in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've created the following to scrape the address details from a website:

```
#import packages
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

postcodelist = []

l = "https://www.whsmith.co.uk/stores/details/?StoreID=" + "1513"
            
html_text = requests.get(l).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text,'html.parser')

info = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'t-store-details__store-address'})

name = info.text.strip()

print(name)
```

How do I format the address so that I can separate the elements out (e.g. address, city, postcode) in to separate columns as per below:

Moor Street Station Queensway | West Midlands | Birmingham | B4 7UL | United Kingdom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need columns, you potentially need a [*DataFrame*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) ? If so, you can use [`get_text`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) to separate the infos with a delimiter, then [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) them and finally make your *DataFrame* with [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) :

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

infos = (soup.find("div", {"class": "t-store-details__store-address"})
         .get_text("\n").split("\n") # add this line/statement
)
​
df = pd.DataFrame([infos]) #use the `columns` parameter to set a custom header
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)
​
                0                    1          2              3           4       5               6
0  Store Address:  Moor Street Station  Queensway  West Midlands  Birmingham  B4 7UL  United Kingdom
```

Comment: **NB**: If you need just a Python string, use this : `soup.find(...).get_text(" | ")`.